# How to check when new device has connected to Wifi in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, python-requests, wifi

I wanted to build a script that would turn off my Philips Hue lights in my room whenever my PlayStation would turn on/connect to the wifi. I got the lights part down but i don’t know how to check if my PlayStation or a new device has connected to the wifi. Any help would be appreciated. (I’m a beginner at python and coding in general)

Comment: it really depends on your setup, but check the router's webpage to see if it lists active clients. If so, you should be able to use some selenium browser automation to get it done

Comment: Unless your router has an API that you can query, this might be hard to do. The simplest way might be to use a library like scapy (or just raw sockets), and listen for broadcasts that the Playstation puts out. IIRC, Playstations like to put out constant broadcasts. If you know the IP of the PS, you can just listen for traffic.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget the router webpage actually does show the devices connected and their IPs, but I don't really know how to get selenium to find the IP and see when its connected

Comment: @Carcigenicate that seems like a good idea, I'll watch some tutorials on how to use scapy and all

Comment: @ctp It's not a very easy library. For this though, you'd only really need to learn the `sniff` function, and know how to access and check parts of packets. Also, you'll need Wireshark for initial testing so you know what traffic you're actually looking for (and to confirm that your PS is as noisy as mine is). If you've never used Wireshark before, it is an essential networking tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your router config setup then assign a static IP address to your playstation.

Then your python script just has to ping that IP address to see if it is online or not

```
subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c", "1", "192.1.1.123"])
```

This will return true if the device is online

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Who is on my WiFi, Heres a link to it https://pypi.org/project/who-is-on-my-wifi/, if that doesn't work you could try setting something up with Wireshark (a program that logs every connection to your IP)

Comment: Good idea, I'll see how it works and learn how to get it to detect when a specific IP is connected I guess